# How to use Android UiSelector with Appium chained for child elements of parent element

Tags: android, appium, ui-automation

I would like to click on first **android.widget.EditText** element from page source bellow. Source does not contain any useful resource-id

I already made xpath query `//*[./*[@text='Österreich']]/*[@class='android.widget.EditText'][1]` the problem is that I can't use xpath query on this place, I can use only UiSelector and I don't have so much experience with complex selectors through UiSelector.

```xml
                        <android.view.View index="6" package="com.android.chrome" class="android.view.View" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[15,711][465,800]" displayed="true">
                          <android.view.View index="0" package="com.android.chrome" class="android.view.View" text="  " checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[15,711][465,800]" displayed="true" />
                          <android.view.View index="1" package="com.android.chrome" class="android.view.View" text="Rechnungsadresse" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[15,711][465,744]" displayed="true" />
                          <android.view.View index="2" package="com.android.chrome" class="android.view.View" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[15,759][465,800]" displayed="true">
                            <android.widget.Spinner index="0" package="com.android.chrome" class="android.widget.Spinner" text="Österreich" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[15,759][465,800]" displayed="true" />
                            <android.widget.EditText index="1" package="com.android.chrome" class="android.widget.EditText" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[15,799][465,800]" displayed="true" />
                            <android.widget.EditText index="2" package="com.android.chrome" class="android.widget.EditText" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[15,799][465,800]" displayed="true" />
                            <android.widget.EditText index="3" package="com.android.chrome" class="android.widget.EditText" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[15,799][465,800]" displayed="true" />
                            <android.widget.EditText index="4" package="com.android.chrome" class="android.widget.EditText" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[15,799][465,800]" displayed="true" />
                            <android.widget.EditText index="5" package="com.android.chrome" class="android.widget.EditText" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[15,799][465,800]" displayed="true" />
```

I tried following but it doesn't work

```java
new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true))
    .scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text("Österreich")
    .fromParent(new UiSelector()
        .childSelector(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.EditText").instance(0))
    )
)
```

as a code in java I'm using `getDriverWait().findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator(uiSelectQuery)).click()`

Do you have any ideas how to do that? Or link for good examples how to use UiSelector?

Android, chained UiSelector, UIAutomator, Appium, UiScrollable

Answer (score 1):

I was actually looking at this question hoping for an answer. While testing more on my own side, I believe the following should work for you

```
new UiSelector().className(android.widget.Spinner).childSelector(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.EditText).index(0))
```

I don't think you actually need index when it's the first child but still.